# Proper way to avoid using mailto body when opening E-Mail client with predefined content (javascript)

Tags: javascript, email, limit, mailto, window.location

**Following Situation**: I'm currently developing a website. On this website there are many articles. If a user wants to send the text of an article to a friend he simply has to click the button "send to a friend" on that article and the default e-mail client pops up with the article as content.

The functionality is working since i solved it with using mailto with javascript:

```
var link = "mailto: + "&subject=Test &body=" + emailbody;
window.location.href = link;
```

**My Problem is**, that i don't want to use the mailto body variable to set the e-mail content since it has limitations on the number of characters.

Is there a nicer solution for this scenario?

Comment: Not really, can you instead send a digest (like just the first paragraph) + a link to article?

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's what we wanted to do at the beginning but i wanted to know if it's possible in a nice way.